# What's the proper way to extract unexported fields from a Golang type?

Tags: reflection, ssh, go, type-conversion, rsa

I'm trying to take an SSH public key (x.crypto.ssh.PublicKey, generated by parsing `authorized_keys`) and extract a plain old `crypto.rsa.PublicKey` from it (I know the key is of type `ssh-rsa`).  That means, in ssh-land, the key is of (unexported) type `rsaPublicKey`.

By using either `reflect.Interface()` or plain old `fmt.Sprintf("%v")` I can get a value that looks like:

```
&{133141753607255377833524803712241410600224583899447743985716492314976605735038858392516407436607315136967439536840885454950028631410155683051419836325912444338003188332463816050354540934271243064035037856360864190161298769948076508355604915775510460445701536855931828420791030023079646791573156484306628882221 35}
```

I know, by reading the ssh package source, that `ssh.rsaPublickey` is in fact defined as the type I want:

```
type rsaPublicKey rsa.PublicKey
```

and therefore this value is already the thing I want.  (In fact, I can, using `"%+v"`, even see that its fields are (of course) named `N` and `E`.)

My problem is that I don't know a better way to make Go believe that this is in fact an `rsa.PublicKey` than to extract each of those numbers into strings with `fmt.Sscan`, and then convert into `big.Int` and `int`, respectively, and then use those two values I just got as the modulus and exponent to create a new `rsa.PublicKey`.

That works, but seems incredibly nasty.  I get that since it's unexported, there's probably no direct route, but surely there's a better way to get the fields than by reconverting their printable representations.

`ssh.PublicKey` does have a `Marshal()` function, but that gives me the wire-format representation, and if I go through there, well, I guess it avoids abusing the type system, but I'd just end up writing my own byte-stream-to-big-Int-to-RSA converter there, which doesn't seem like it really helps.  At that point I might just as well start with the `authorized_keys` file and parse it myself, and that seems dumb too.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reflect` to convert that interface value back to the original `rsa.PublicKey`:

```
rsaKey := reflect.ValueOf(sshKey).
    Convert(reflect.TypeOf(&rsa.PublicKey{})).Interface().(*rsa.PublicKey)
```

Playground with a similar example: http://play.golang.org/p/bcYhYHrIl_.

Comment: That only works because everything is within the package `main` otherwise it would panic at runtime.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: please stop commenting unless you've tried these. This works, and is roughly equivalent to my answer. I've tried both these directly with the ssh package. Ainar-G, good idea on the `Convert`, I forgot about that in the reflect package.

Comment: This certainly does the trick, and doesn't mess around with the individual fields.  It's pretty terrifying, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @JimB Actually there is a way to check. [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) has `ConvertibleTo(u Type) bool` method.

Comment: @Ainar-G, oh, of course! I'll just remove that other comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use reflection to extract the `N` and `E` values from the `rsaPublicKey` in the `ssh.PublicKey` interace:

```
// pub, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(authKeyData)
val := reflect.ValueOf(pub).Elem()
n := val.FieldByName("N").Interface().(*big.Int)
e := val.FieldByName("E").Interface().(int)

rsaKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
    N: n,
    E: e,
}
```

Comment: But there is no `pub` in this scope, it's not exported. Even if it was that would panic at runtime.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: no it wont panic if it's the correct key type. `pub` is just the parsed `ssh.PublicKey`. http://play.golang.org/p/bhsdKWGj_u

Comment: Where did `authKeyData` come from then? The OP said he's trying to get the value of this field;  `ssh.rsaPublickey` you didn't get past that problem you just provided the implementation he said he didn't want "might as well start with the authorized_keys file and parse it myself" ....

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: `authKeyData` is just the file contents. He already has that available, and parsed. That's the premise of the question.

Comment: Yes that thing I quoted in the question where the OP said he knows he can do that but doesn't want to... Good suggestion JimB! One hell of a solution!

Comment: I wasn't clear: I'm using ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey() to get the data out of authorized_keys.  If I were to skip using the ssh package entirely, I *could* just parse authorized_keys and convert the key data into an rsa.PublicKey directly--but ParseAuthorizedKey() works nicely, except that the data ends up in an opaque ssh.PublicKey rather than something I can work with in the rsa package.  Hence the question.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: the question was to avoid re-implementing the parser, or interpreting the string representation. While not pretty, this avoids both, and with sufficient checks on the reflection, won't panic.

Comment: He got the value by using `fmt.Sprintf("%v")` and then parsed it. Much the same as parsing that file except without the uneeded use of `reflect`. Please read the question more closely before trying to answer it. My answer may not be useful but it's the answer to the question that was asked, @AdamThornton wanted to know if he could somehow break the rules of exporting, what he's doing right now is as close as it gets.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: take a breath and please read OP's comment, he *is* using ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey().

Comment: I don't know what you guys are referring to with reflection but I guarentee you there is no direct way of accessing an unexported field using reflection. It *always* panics. Whatever else you're talking about doing is not the same as accessing the unexported field which the OP would like to have exported in that `ssh` package. He may as well just print the string and parse it, or get rid of that `ssh` package and read the file as you've suggested.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: please stop commenting until you compile and run the example code. This works. Ainar-G's works (BTW, you can *read* unexported fields with reflect http://play.golang.org/p/xFjUBUU5a8)

Comment: Both this and the version using Convert actually work in my use case.  This one is much more like my initial approach, in that it depends on knowing some stuff about the RSA key's internal structure--but it beats my initial approach in that it avoids using String as a really low-budget serialization mechanism.  Given the fact that I know I have an RSA SSH key that I am getting out of an authorized_keys entry, I'm going to go with the Convert()-based approach, but this one was much easier to wrap my head around.  Thanks!